# Ubuntu : Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

trying to install this, I am getting the 'Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages' error message.

## Apache version

Server version: Apache/2.4.2 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jun 27 2012 07:23:35

```
# aptitude install libapache2-mod-wsgi

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2.2-common{ab} libapache2-mod-wsgi
 0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 299 kB of archives. After unpacking 1,047 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Conflicts: apache2.2-common but 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.5 is to be installed.
 apache2.2-common : Depends: apache2.2-bin (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.5) but it is not going to     be installed.
                Depends: apache2-utils but it is not going to be installed.
 apache2-bin : Conflicts: apache2.2-common but 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.5 is to be installed.
 apache2-data : Conflicts: apache2.2-common but 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.5 is to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

 Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     apache2.2-common [Not Installed]
2)     libapache2-mod-wsgi [Not Installed]


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Any help appretiated

Comment: This question should belong to [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: [Use aptitude instead of apt-get. It is more intelligent. It not only will handle downgrading conflicting packages for you, but will make a series of recommendations asking you which of many possible suggested working scenarios you would like.](http://askubuntu.com/a/451078/5786)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Option 1:** You can try:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The 'upgrade' option tries to solve all dependencies in installed packages. Often this is enough to solve broken packages

**Option 2**: If your package was installed from a 'deb' file and not from repositories, it may be that the new one you are trying to install is causing a conflict, and as a result you need first to remove the previous version of the package.
You can do that from Software Center or directly with:

```
sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-wsgi
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am also new to Ubuntu, installed today. I was installing VLC and its giving me the same problem, what to do ?

Comment: upgrade may be damaging to the system if you don't know what you are doing. It

Answer (score 3):

I have also the same problem for sudo apt-get install npm.

Tried

```
sudo apt-get remove npm
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

then

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

then
    sudo apt-get install nodejs
    sudo apt-get install npm

solved for me!

Answer (score 2):

This will work for virtualenv pip wheel errorcode1 problems and also E unable to locate package problems

```
    sudo apt-get update

    sudo apt-get install python-software-properties

    sudo apt-get install apt-file

    sudo apt-file update

    sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

    sudo apt-get install <your filename>
```

Comment: `sudo apt` instead of `sudo apt-get` should work as well

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was doing a quiet installation, using the `-qq` flags. Turning these off showed the dependency issue for me.